# Oracle SQL nested max function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a function which returns the maximal distance between all the items, as a number.
I understand it should be like a nested for loop and am having trouble with the query nesting.

I have a table:

```
create table MediaItems (
  MID NUMBER(9,0),
  TITLE VARCHAR2 (200),
  PROD_YEAR NUMBER(4),
  TITLE_LENGTH NUMBER(4),
  CONSTRAINT mid_pk PRIMARY KEY (MID)
);
```

and I need to return the maximal result of the distance calculation between all the item pairs. distance being the squared difference between the production years of the given items(PROD_YEAR).

I would appreciate any help/advice on how to nest queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular calculation -- assuming the values are all positive -- just square the difference between the minimum and maximum values:

```
select power(max(prod_year) - min(prod_year), 2)
from mediaitems mi;
```

This can easily be modified to handle negative values, but that seems unlikely in a column named `prod_year`.

Comment: it seems unlikely to me too that the year would be negative, I've used your quick and easy solution, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that negatives are an issue here. Are you thinking of log()?

Answer (score 0):

A `cross join` should do the trick - it pairs every item with every other item, giving the "nested loops" effect you wanted here.

```
SELECT     MAX(POWER(a.prod_year - b.prod_year), 2)
FROM       MediaItems a
CROSS JOIN MediaItems b
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing values with a single dimension the maximum distance comes just from the maximum and minimum elements. Any other pair will give you a lower distance so the best way to evaluate distance in your table is:

```
SELECT abs(MAX(prod_year) - MIN(prod_year))
FROM MediaItems
```

If you have only positive values for prod_year you don't need to use the abs function. I don't understand why you need the squared difference in with single dimension values.